# @QuarkusTest-Annotation + Mockito Result in ClassLoader Errors

Tags: java, junit, mockito, quarkus

Following this tutorial: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus_mock I was creating my first tests planing to mock away my DAO. Soon ran into stacktraces like this one:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: Failed to create test instance
at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.initTestState(QuarkusTestExtension.java:820)
at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:784)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:72)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:77)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:267)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:768)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.initTestState(QuarkusTestExtension.java:812)
... 63 more

Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
ClassCastException occurred while creating the mockito mock :
class to mock : 'test.a.Bean', loaded by classloader : 'QuarkusClassLoader:Quarkus Base Runtime ClassLoader'
created class : 'org.mockito.codegen.Bean$MockitoMock$1354312240', loaded by classloader : 'net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader@1b485c8b'
proxy instance class : 'org.mockito.codegen.Bean$MockitoMock$1354312240', loaded by classloader : 'net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader@1b485c8b'
instance creation by : ObjenesisInstantiator

You might experience classloading issues, please ask the mockito mailing-list.

at io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.internal.CreateMockitoMocksCallback.createMockAndSetTestField(CreateMockitoMocksCallback.java:44)
at io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.internal.CreateMockitoMocksCallback.afterConstruct(CreateMockitoMocksCallback.java:28)
... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.mockito.codegen.Bean$MockitoMock$1354312240 to test.a.Bean
at java.base/java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3606)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.ensureMockIsAssignableToMockedType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:94)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:52)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:43)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:53)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:84)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1954)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1865)
... 70 more
```

To isolate the problem I create a minimal example.
**Test-Class**

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectMock;

@QuarkusTest // (1)
public class Tester {
    
    @InjectMock // (2)
    Bean mock; // (3)

    @Test
    public void test() {


//      Bean mock = Mockito.mock(Bean.class); (4)

        when(mock.greet()).thenReturn("hello there");
        Assertions.assertThat(mock.greet()).isEqualTo("hello there");
    }
}
```

But if I remove (1),(2) and (3) and **use** (4). It works just fine.

**Class-To-Mock**

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class Bean {
    

    public String greet() {
        return "Moin Moin!";
    }
}
```

I found lots of people having the same problem had:

- Duplicate Mockito dependency
- Expected Mockito to work out child-parent-relationship

None of this was my problem.

The problems seems to correlate with *@QuarkusTest*. Somehow the Proxy-object(the mock) and the mocked class are from different classloaders.

We are using *quarkus version 1.12.1.Final* and the extensions are configured by the bom, therefor they should work together. Did I misunderstood anything?

Comment: Have you tried Quarkus `1.13.7.Final` or `2.0.2.Final`? This should definitely work

Comment: Yes you are right, changing to 1.13.7.Final fixed the issue. Thank you @geoand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As geoand pointed out using **1.13.7.Final** of quarkus did solve the problem.